# incompatible conversion from int[] to int

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Solution {
public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
    int [] arr = new int[nums.length];
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] != nums[i+1]){
            arr[i] = nums[i];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

}

this is my code and I am having error ::
***incompatible conversion from int[] to int.***

Comment: You are returning `int`, not `int[]`

Comment: Your condition `nums[i] != nums[i+1]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return statement is returning the `int` array, but your declared return type is an `int` primitive.  You should return the `int` array instead:

```
public int[] removeDuplicates(int[] nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions are right but i noticed  another problem in your solution. Let's say that the array has 10 numbers.
You start from i = 0; and you continue until the i < array.legth. But in your comparison you compare num[i] and num [i+1]. So when i = 9 that is the last index of the array, the comparison will be if num[9] == num[10],so you will have a runtime error, because there is not index 10.
one think you can do is this:

```
class Solution {
public int[] removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
   int [] arr = new int[nums.length];
   for(int i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++){
    if(nums[i] != nums[i+1]){
        arr[i] = nums[i];
    }
}
return arr;
```

}

You got to change the array.length to array.length-1.
And if you still stuck that's an existed soltion for youe problem.
[remove dublicates](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-remove-duplicate-element-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

Already said the return type must be `int[]` too.

```
public int[] removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0) {
        return nums;
    }
    int[] arr = nums.clone();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[j]) {
            ++j;
            arr[j] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copy(arr, j + 1);
}
```

The removal of consecutive duplicates must be done a bit different. Above a not so elegant solution. *Not tested.*